# Against the law to spray-clean not according to label directions?

Tags: united-states, consumer-products, law, marketing, cleaning

I have a bottle of Clorox Clean-Up Cleaner with Bleach, marketed for sale in the United States. Its label reads, in part (and with emphasis removed):

> Directions for use: It is a violation of Federal law to use this product in a manner inconsistent with its labeling. Use only in well-ventilated areas. Before use, open windows and turn on fan. If vapors bother you, leave room while product is working.

(Other, similar products have a similar statement.)

- Is it really a violation of federal law to use the product in a manner inconsistent with its labeling? Suppose I *didn't* open windows before cleaning my bathroom: did I violate the law?
- What law? — citation, please.
- Is there a punishment prescribed if one is found guilty?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it is against the US Federal law. Yes, in theory it can cost you $1000 or 30 days' jail.

- Pesticides are regulated in the US by the [United States Environment Protection Agency](http://www.epa.gov/), in accordance with the [Federal Insecticide, Fungicide, and Rodenticide Act (FIFRA)](http://www.epa.gov/oecaagct/lfra.html).
- Clorox Clean Up Cleaner With Bleach [contains](http://www.clorox.com/products/clorox-clean-up-cleaner/ingredients-and-safety/) ingredients that are considered pesticides. (I'm not yet sure which ones are the ones that are considered pesticides.)
- Hence, the [Chlorox Cleaner label](http://www.epa.gov/pesticides/chem_search/ppls/005813-00016-20070320.pdf) is [registered](http://iaspub.epa.gov/apex/pesticides/f?p=PPLS:8:0::NO::P8_PUID:26728) with the EPA's [Pesticide Produce Labelling System](http://iaspub.epa.gov/apex/pesticides/f?p=PPLS:1).
- As explained in the EPA's [Pesticide Labeling Questions & Answers - General Labeling](http://www.epa.gov/pesticides/regulating/labels/labels_faq/lr_faq_10.html), this implies that the label is required by the EPA regulations to contain the quoted warning:

> **Is it true that the manufacturer's label on a CONSUMER (as opposed to agricultural, etc.) pesticide imposes a legal obligation on the purchaser to use the product only as directed on the label? LC10-0330; 4/6/10**
>
> FIFRA sec. 12(a)(2)(G) makes it a violation of federal law for any person "to use any registered pesticide in a manner inconsistent with its labeling." All registered pesticides, including registered consumer pesticides, must bear the statement:
>
> "It is a violation of Federal law to use this product in a manner inconsistent with its labeling." 40 CFR 156.10(i)(2)(ii).
>
> Section 2(ee) of FIFRA provides limited exceptions to what is considered "in a manner inconsistent with" labeling. For instance it is not a violation to use a pesticide at a rate lower than that specified on the label unless the label specifically prohibits deviation from the specified rate.

The penalties are described in [FIFRA Section 14](http://www.ag.senate.gov/download/fifra), and for "private applicators" are limited to:

- Civil Penalties: Not more than $1,000 if you do it after receiving a citation or written warning from the EPA.
- Criminal Penalties: "fined not more than $1,000, or imprisoned for not more than 30 days, or both."

Comment: I just want to say for the record. I'm a certified applicator, and this answer is excellent.

Answer (score 6):

It might refer to the OSHA Act however, the OSHA act obviously doesn't apply to you unless you are an employee or an employer using bleach-based products in your business

> "Section 5(b) of the OSHA Act states that "each employee shall comply with occupational safety and health standards and all rules, regulations and orders issued pursuant to the OSHA Act which are applicable to his own actions and conduct." In addition, the courts have repeatedly held that under Section 5(a)(2) of the Act (29 U.S.C. 654(a)(2)), employers are responsible for ensuring worker protection. OSHA and the courts have concluded that respirators and other protective equipment must be used during cleanups that require bleach if requested by the employee or required by the employer.

[OSHA Regulations on Use of Bleach](http://www.ehow.com/list_6707250_osha-regulations-use-bleach.html)

[Section 5](http://www.osha.gov/pls/oshaweb/owadisp.show_document?p_table=OSHACT&p_id=3359)

Comment: +1, many thanks, but I wonder whether there's *another* law which applies more generally.

Comment: @msh210 probably a blanket clause, but I can envision dumping toxic chemicals in the toilet or using them to poison someone would certainly be a violation of the law, and may well be what is intended with such clauses (in order for the company to cover themselves in case a victim of such poisoning sues the product manufacturer for damages based on "you didn't print on the box that it wasn't supposed to be used to poison my husband" or some such nonsense, lawsuits which in the US are sadly all too common).